# Erro ao tentar fazer login com React e Redux Saga

Tags: react, redux

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição para pegar sessão em um API, ela é com o sistema de oauth2, onde tenho que enviar um form-urlencoded com alguns dados e ela me retorna um token. Porém não to conseguindo fazer a requisição, ta dando erro  400.

Segue meu saga:

```
import { takeLatest, call, put, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import history from '../../../services/history';
import api from '../../../services/api';

import { signInSuccess } from './actions';

export function* signIn({ payload }) {
  const { email, password, grant_type } = payload;

  const client_id = 'aVgjhEBcnN-ytRrewsWJrSpoKnh';
  const client_secret = 'q4fYtRGIkmLJKtx9Y5MaUYFPPdasd2QD4hTI4Gds45tgfSAdlkj';
  const token = 'Basic ' + btoa(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`);

  const headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    token,
  };

  const response = yield call(
    api.post,
    'auth/token',
    {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      grant_type: grant_type,
    },
    { headers }
  );

  console.log(response);

  history.push('/dashboard');
}

export default all([takeLatest('@auth/SIGN_IN_REQUEST', signIn)]);
```

Segue print do insomnia da requisição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora segue o print do erro que da ao fazer a requisição na página de login:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é, o que to fazendo de errado que tá me retornando erro 400?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz um teste utilizando o Postman, fazendo um post para o endereço que aparece no seu print de erro:

https://charler-node-api.herokuapp.com/auth/token

Eu configurei o header como basic authentication, utilizando as credenciais que você informou no seu Saga.

O problema é o nome de um dos campos. No seu Insomnia, tem um campo chamado "username", no seu Saga, tem um campo chamado "email". Se você trocar email por username, o erro 400 deixa de ocorrer. Segue retorno que eu recebi:

```
{
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiNWUzOGJiNWY2NjI4YjYwNjRhOTU3NmMzIiwiZGF0ZSI6IjIwMjAtMDItMDRUMTI6MTc6MjguMzIzWiIsImlhdCI6MTU4MDgxODY0OH0.ZUK2a61LXAv5ADGc2Lo1CsQLEal_CYXMx5xc7_5nJ6U",
    "user": {
        "id": "5e38bb5f6628b6064a9576c3",
        "email": "admin@email.com"
    }
}
```